# Unit test Flask login function gives wrong response

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I am trying to unit test my Flask application. But when unit testing with unittest it won't let me login.

This is my test script. test_register_page and test_login_page both work! The test_user_registration function works as well, but I know this is not the way to test the register function. I am now just saving it to the database. But when trying to login it  will not give  me a status_code 201. So that means my unit test for login is not working correct.

```
import unittest
from damage_detection import create_app, db
from damage_detection.config import config_dict
from damage_detection.models import User


class UserTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app=create_app(config=config_dict['testing'])
        self.appctx=self.app.app_context()
        self.appctx.push()
        self.client=self.app.test_client()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.drop_all()
        self.appctx.pop()
        self.app=None
        self.client =None

    def test_register_page(self):
        r = self.client.get("/register")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
        
    def test_login_page(self):
        r = self.client.get("/login")
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

    def test_user_registration(self):
        user = User(username="testuser", email="testuser@company.com", password="password", image_file="default.jpg")
        db.session.add(user)
        users = User.query.all()
        assert user in users

    def test_login(self):
        data={
            "email":"testuser@company.com",
            "password":"password"
        }
        response=self.client.post('/login',data=data)
        print(response.status_code)
    
        assert response.status_code == 201
```

This is my login function:

```
@users.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('main.home'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

Do i need to give other data to the login function?

If you need more information about my files please let me know. Everything else is working correct so it is not a fault in my application code :)

Comment: Hi, which status code are you getting instead? This might help understand what you are returning that is not 201

Answer (score 0):

it would be easier to debug this knowing which status code are you getting back from the test. As it fails I guess it is different from **201**.

By looking over your code I see some redirects. By Flask documentation `flask.redirect()` method defaults the code to **302**. This might be the issue.

Comment: It gives a code  of 200, if I am correct this not the good  one. If we are trying to login?

Comment: When you fail the login you are just flashing, flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger') try return something so you know it failed on the test. And check if you manage to specify a return code 201 on success